# What are the typefaces or fonts that are used for the Marvel Super Heroes Role Playing Game? (FASERIP)

Tags: fonts, marvel-faserip

What are the typefaces or fonts that are used for the cover and internal texts of the Marvel Super Heroes Role Playing Game by TSR?

Preferably for the Advanced Judges and Players books.

Off the top of my head a number of different fonts were used: main cover, credits page, table of contents page, chapter header text, body text, and section header text (the last two may simply be different sizes and bold or not of the same font).

I would not mind also knowing the Basic, Basic Revised, and Ultimate Powers book fonts either... as all the books may have used the same font set.

Comment: Isn't this question almost opinion-based?

Comment: This isn't opinion based; there's going to be specific factual answers.

Comment: The *Ultimate Powers Book* (1987)—the only *Marvel Super Heroes* product on my shelf—lists Kim N. Lindau as that book's typographer; maybe other books have a similar credit if detective work is your jam? However, the interior text looks like the same unexceptional sans serif font used in many TSR products of the era. (Even the lower case gs are boring; I couldn't find any ampersands.) Is there something about the font(s) in the books in question that makes the font(s) interesting? Maybe include an example?

Comment: If you attempt to identify the font(s) using any of the websites that are suggested by Google if you ask for "font identification", and do not find answers to your question, you might want to consider whether asking on [graphicdesign.se] would be appropriate.

Comment: @HeyICanChan For a particular fan project I am assisting with, I need to use the exact font if possible, or one as close as humanly possible, otherwise. With all the font info available for D&D, I'm a little surprised that other TSR projects didn't get the same treatment.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Also, I believe most of the other books list Betty Elmore as one who did the typography, at least the two advanced books list her.

Comment: @nijineko What version/edition? From what I can tell there are different versions.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question, the Advanced rule set, though Basic and UPB is also welcome. Only the original edition of the game has that particular combo, I thought? In any case that would be the MSHRPG FASERIP system.

Comment: 1) Can you include a photo of the cover, and  a photo of sample inside text?  2) have you tried font identification tools online,  and to what effect?